# Filling object with CSV file returning error

Tags: java, servlets

I Have a CSV file, that contains the following information:

```
Santa Catarina,Florianópolis,São José,Biguaçu,Palhoça
Rio grande do Sul,Porto alegre,,,
Paraná,Curitiba,Londrina,Ponta Grossa,
```

Every first data from each line, is a state, and the following are the cities of this respective state.

I have two objects, State and City, State(Estado) have Name and an `ArrayList` of cities, and City(Cidade) have a bunch of attributes.

To read my CSV, here it's my code:

```
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Pedro Sarkis\\Desktop\\ex3.csv"));

ArrayList<Estado> estados = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Cidade> cidade = new ArrayList<>();

// String estados2[];
int i = 1;
String line = r.readLine();
try {
    while (line != null) {
        //  System.out.println("Line " + i + ": " + line);
        String[] campos = line.split(",");

        for (int j = 1; j < campos.length; j++) {
            Cidade c = new Cidade();
            c.setNome(campos[j]);
            cidade.add(c);
        }

        Estado e = new Estado(campos[0], cidade);
        estados.add(e);

        cidade.clear();

        line = r.readLine();
        i++;
    }
} finally {
    r.close();
}
```

The problem is that I just can't limit the Cities to their respective states.

I was testing using `.clear()` to kinda reset my list after each `while`, but it's not working, because it resets all of my past data, and without using `.clear()`, all my States receive all the cities.

Answer (score 0):

Using clear() will not work in this case, since previous elements in the list still point to the same object. Thus, it will change the value of the previous elements too. Change your code from

```
cidade.clear();
```

to

```
cidade = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: If the solution works for you, make sure you upvote the answer/ mark as solved.

Answer (score 0):

Each instance of `Estado` needs to have a *brand new* List.  If you pass the same List object to every Estado construction, they are all sharing the same List object.  Calling `clear()` does not make a new or different List object, it just removes elements from the same List object.

There are two ways you can accomplish this.

First approach: You can change the Estado class to use an object-oriented practice known as *defensive copying.*  The Estado class would copy the List argument given to its constructor, so other code is not able to change the Estado instance by altering the List.  This way, only calling methods of Estado can alter the Estado instance.  This allows us to say that the Estado class *encapsulates* its data, by having exclusive control over its own state.

```
public class Estado {
    private String state;

    private List<String> cities;

    public Estado(String state,
                  List<String> cities) {

        this.state = state;

        // Copying the List, so any later modifications cannot affect
        // this instance.
        this.cities = new ArrayList<>(cities);
    }
}
```

Second approach:  Create a new city ArrayList for every line you read.

```
while (line != null) {

    String[] campos = line.split(","); 

    cidade = new ArrayList<>();

    // ...
```